# Understanding Time#utc?

Tags: ruby, time, utc

As I understand, UTC means a time is given in timezone +00:00. But Ruby thinks different in `Time#utc?`. I've observed this in Ruby 2.5.1:

```
a = Time.new(2018,6,13, 9,0,0, '+00:00')
# => 2018-06-13 09:00:00 +0000 

b = Time.utc(2018,6,13, 9,0,0)
# => 2018-06-13 09:00:00 UTC 

a == b 
# => true

a.utc? 
# => false (WHY???)

b.utc?
# => true
```

IMHO, `a.utc?` should return true. Is there any explanation?

**Addition:** From the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Time.html#method-i-utc-3F) for Time#utc?

> Returns true if *time* represents a time in UTC (GMT).

What exactly means "representing a time in UTC/GMT"? An offset of 0 is not enough, obviously.

Comment: UTC is a time standard, not a time zone. GMT is the timezone with offset +00:00. While they are mostly equivalent, they should not be confused. UTC is what timezones are offset from. Thus, GMT is +00:00 offset from UTC. In this sense, UTC does not have an offset, because it is what the offset is measured *from*.

Comment: @Amadan `a.gmt?` is also `false`. Ruby seems to use UTC and GMT interchangeably.

Comment: @Stefan It does... That's Ruby being wrong in terminology (associating GMT with UTC instead of with +00:00). From docs: "The `Time` class treats GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) and UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) as equivalent. _GMT is the older way of referring to these baseline times but persists in the names of calls on POSIX systems._" (emphasis mine).

Comment: You can also look at it this way: `2018-06-13 09:00:00 +0000` is a specific time in Britain; `2018-06-13 09:00:00 UTC` is a specific time _everywhere_.

Comment: @mudasobwa: Not so... GB already uses DST, and switches from GMT to BST (British Summer Time). GMT is +00:00, BST and CET are both +01:00

Comment: @Amadan ah, indeed.

Comment: _"BST and CET are both +01:00"_ – although they don't "occur" at the same time since the time zones are shifted simultaneously (GMT → BST, CET → CEST)

Comment: @Stefan a small nitpick - I'm sure you didn't intend this ambiguity, but - *these* specific time zones are switched simultaneously, as are now all time zones in Europe among the ones that do employ DST; however, that is not true of other parts of the world, where [many countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country) have their own rules as to when they switch.

Comment: @Amadan rewording a comment results in at least one typo. Of course: _these_ ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation-wise, Ruby's (i.e. MRI) internal [time structure](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/75d25ede15e664ee0048ebc4e84e9e34838c2313/time.c#L1600-L1605) has a `gmt` field which specifies the time's type:

```c
PACKED_STRUCT_UNALIGNED(struct time_object {
    wideval_t timew; /* time_t value * TIME_SCALE.  possibly Rational. */
    struct vtm vtm;
    uint8_t gmt:3; /* 0:localtime 1:utc 2:fixoff 3:init */
    uint8_t tm_got:1;
});
```

The `utc?` method merely checks whether `gmt` is `1`.

Therefore, a time instance in local time or a time instance with explicit offset will never be `utc?`, even if your system's timezone offset is UTC+0:

```
Time.local(2018)      #=> 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Time.local(2018).utc? #=> false

Time.new(2018)        #=> 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
Time.new(2018).utc?   #=> false
```

as opposed to a time instance created via [`utc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Time.html#method-c-utc): (note that the offset is shown as `UTC`)

```
Time.utc(2018)        #=> 2018-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
Time.utc(2018).utc?   #=> true
```

You could check the [`utc_offset`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Time.html#method-i-utc_offset) instead:

```
t = Time.new(2018) #=> 2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
t.utc_offset       #=> 0
t.utc_offset.zero? #=> true
```